# What language is this?

Tags: golfing-language

I'm working on something and came across this after I interpreted some brainfuck code. It looks like another esoteric language but I'm not sure what. Anyone know?

```
(CB;:9]~}5Yz2Vw/StQr*)M:,+*)('&%$#"!~}|{zyx875t"2~p0nm,+jch'`%
```

Comment: Where did you find this? Context can give clues.

Comment: @orip Based on what I've seen, maybe it's CJam or GolfScript? This is going by the snippets of code I've seen, I've never worked with either.

Comment: It was in a challenge for a programming competition.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI By the way, my name is ORLP lowercase, not ORIP ;)

Comment: @MichaelYousef Which one? One on StackExchange? If it was here, it should be labeled.

Comment: No, it was a past challenge for International Capture the Flag. I want to ideally run the code and see what it returns. It should most likely print out some string that is an answer.

Comment: Malbolge programs can be identified by decreasing ascii sequences like ``~}|{zyx``. I noticed that only after seeing the answer, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After one second of Googling a portion of the string (`5Yz2Vw`), I found the following page:

http://www.xchg.info/wiki/index.php?title=ICTF_2011_:_Challenge_13_-_250_Points

On that page it's deduced the code is Malbolge.

Comment: you beat me by a couple of seconds, also [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_malbolge_online.php) is an online IDE to run the code

Comment: When I run the code on it, I get an error though. Any suggestions? Also, the only reason we know it's Malbolge is because there's an answer somewhere. We would need to find this out in the dark.

Comment: strange for me it ouputs: EvIl!  , and yes thats capital i lower l

Comment: So I figured out that there's supposed to be some whitespace in it from the link you have. When I ran the brainfuck code through the interpreter, I got the exact string I posted. When I interpreted without whitespace, nothing. When I interpreted what they posted on that site with the whitespace, it suddenly worked. Odd.

Also I still have no idea how they figured out it was Malbolge. They googled and found some stuff that linked it to Malebolge -> Malbolge, I have no idea how that's what they got.

Comment: I figured it out. If you look at Wiki's page on esoteric languages, you see that Malbolge talks about circles of hell, and that this code should likely be Malbolge.